# Sphinx docs displaying locally but not at URL when pushed to GitHub

Tags: python, github, python-sphinx

I generated Python docs using Sphinx using `make html`. When I opened `index.html` in my browser the docs displayed as expected and all links worked as expected.

I then committed all docs and pushed to a branch in GitHub.

When I access the url `https://<my company>.github.io/<my repo>/` the page displays but the CSS isn't working and some of the links do not work. Does anybody know why this might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that some files were missing. After reading [this](https://help.github.com/en/articles/files-that-start-with-an-underscore-are-missing) I added an empty `.nojekyll` which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this might be that some files like `_static` and `_sources` are missing from the directory that contains `index.html` file. By default, Jekyll ignores directories starting with `_`. Adding `.nojekyll` will signal to GitHub Pages to not use Jekyll for building your site, and hence it will not ignore files like `_static` and `_sources` directories.

If you want to use `sphinx-build` and copy the html files to another branch like `gh-pages`, you can use a setup like below:

```
- name: Build Sphinx documentation
  run: |
    cd docs
    sphinx-build . build  
    touch build/.nojekyll

- name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
  uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
  with:
    github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    publish_dir: ./docs/build/
    publish_branch: gh-pages
    destination_dir: docs
```

In my case, I was missing the `touch build/.nojekyll` part and thus the `_static` and `_sources` directories were missing.